# spark partitioning breaks the lazy evaluation chain and triggers error which I cannot catch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

When doing the re-partitioning spark is breaking the lazy-evaluation-chain and triggers the error which I cannot control/catch.

```scala
//simulation of reading a stream from s3
def readFromS3(partition: Int) : Iterator[(Int, String)] = {
    Iterator.tabulate(3){idx => 
        // simulate an error only on partition 3 record 2
        (idx, if(partition == 3 && idx == 2) throw new RuntimeException("error") else s"elem $idx on partition $partition" )
    }    
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4))
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex((partitionIndex, iter) => readFromS3(partitionIndex))

// I can do whatever I want here

//this is what triggers the evaluation of the iterator 
val partitionedRdd = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))

// I can do whatever I want here

//desperately trying to catch the exception 
partitionedRdd.foreachPartition{ iter => 
    try{
        iter.foreach(println)
    }catch{
        case _ => println("error caught")
    }
}
```

**Before you comment be aware that:**

1. This is an over-simplification of my real world application
2. I know the reading from s3 can be done differently and that I should use sc.textFile. I don't have control over this, I cannot change it.
3. I understand what the problem is : when partitioning, spark is breaking the lazy-chain-evaluation and triggers the error.  I have to do it !
4. I don't claim there is a bug in spark, spark needs to evaluate the records for shuffling
5. I can only do whatever I want :

   - between the reading from s3 and partitioning
   - after partitioning
6. I can write my own custom partitioner

**Given the restrictions mentioned above, can I work around this ? Is there a solution ?**

Comment: The problem is not reproducible with code you've shared. There is however an issue with `readFromS3(iter.next))`, which doesn't take into account empty partitions.

Comment: @user10938362, I don't think there was any issue with it, but just for the clarity sake I changed the mapPartition with mapPartitionWithIndex in order to avoid the iterator.next.

Comment: Understand that you cannot catch error,  but what error is actually generated from Logs?

Comment: @skjagini I don't think it helps in any way, it's a MalformedInputException ( the files that I read are sometimes broken).

Comment: The try/catch block is executing on each partition, but you have broken partition upfront, may be you need to handle val partitionedRdd = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2)) ? Just thinking out lout here, otherwise you are hitting an exception that is not passed onto framework from properly, i.e readFromS3 should be investigated further

Comment: @skjagini, indeed having a try/catch in the foreachPartition is too late, unfortunately there's no way I know to catch the error before that. I tried a map/flatMap with a try/catch inside before the partitioning but it does not work ... of course due to lazy evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to have an EvaluateAheadIterator ( one which evaluates the head of the buffer before the iterator.next is called )

```scala
import scala.collection.AbstractIterator
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

class EvalAheadIterator[+A](iter : Iterator[A]) extends AbstractIterator[A] {

  private val bufferedIter  : BufferedIterator[A] = iter.buffered

  override def hasNext: Boolean =
    if(bufferedIter.hasNext){
      try{
          bufferedIter.head //evaluate the head and trigger potential exceptions
          true
      }catch{
          case NonFatal(e) =>
            println("caught exception ahead of time")
            false
      }
    }else{
        false
    }


  override def next() : A = bufferedIter.next()
}
```

Now we should apply the EvalAheadIterator in a mapPartition:

```scala
//simulation of reading a stream from s3
def readFromS3(partition: Int) : Iterator[(Int, String)] = {
    Iterator.tabulate(3){idx => 
        // simulate an error only on partition 3 record 2
        (idx, if(partition == 3 && idx == 2) throw new RuntimeException("error") else s"elem $idx on partition $partition" )
    }    
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4))
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex((partitionIndex, iter) => readFromS3(partitionIndex))
            .mapPartitions{iter => new EvalAheadIterator(iter)}

// I can do whatever I want here

//this is what triggers the evaluation of the iterator 
val partitionedRdd = rdd.partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(2))

// I can do whatever I want here

//desperately trying to catch the exception 
partitionedRdd.foreachPartition{ iter => 
    try{
        iter.foreach(println)
    }catch{
        case _ => println("error caught")
    }
}
```